Notification badge not updating when app is in the background
In my app, a locally generated notification is provided at a certain time. The notification generates and displays as expected. When the app is open, the notification badge updates to show a single notification (again, as expected), however, when the app is in the background, the badge does not update.
//This code schedules a notification for 7 days before a date (action.date)

private func scheduleNotificationIfRequired() {
    let sevenDaysBeforeActionDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: action.date)!
    var triggerDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: sevenDaysBeforeActionDate)
    

    triggerDateComponents.hour = 21
    triggerDateComponents.minute = 51
    
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Upcoming Deadline"
    content.body = "Action Required by: \(formattedDate(from: action.date))"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDateComponents, repeats: false)
    
    let identif = action.action + action.name
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identif, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) 
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    var viewRouter: ViewRouter?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        return true
    }
    
    // Handle notification when the app is in the foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        // Increment the badge number on the app icon
        let currentbadge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber

        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = currentbadge + 1
        

        completionHandler([.badge, .sound, .banner]) // Ensure notification banner is displayed
        
        // If the notification is tapped while the app is in the foreground, handle it here
        handleNotification(notification)
    }
    
//This is the code that doesn’t work as expected. “here” is never printed to terminal

    // Handle notification when the app is in the background or terminated
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
       // Increment the badge number on the app icon
       let currentbadge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber
       UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = currentbadge + 1
       print(currentbadge)
       print("here")
       print(UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber)
       
       completionHandler()
   }
}


The didReceive delegate method is only called if the user interacts with custom options you have added to your notification.
An app does not have an opportunity to execute any code when a notification is delivered while it is in the background.
You can set a badge value that will be set when your notification is delivered through the badge property of your UNNotificationContent.
The tricky part with this, is it is an absolute value, not a change to the current badge value.
If you schedule three notifications with badge values 1,2 and 3 then the badge will be set to 3 when notification 3 fires, even if the events associated with the previous notifications have been actioned (and so the badge needs to be 1).
To work around this you will need to cancel and reschedule your local notifications each time the user takes some action in your app that affects the badge.
ie:

You schedule 3 notifications with badges 1,2,3 and 4
Notification 1 is delivered, setting the badge to 1
Notification 2 is delivered setting the badge to 2
The user takes some action in your app that sets the badge back to 1.
At this point you need to cancel the remaining notifications and then re-schedule them with badge values 2 and 3


great, thank you. Do you know how that should be modified to do as I intend? Sorry, I'm new to Swiftui and all the answers I found online prior to posting don't seem to help solve the issue

It's not possible to update the badge from a local notification while your app is in the background. You can send a push notification with a badge number.

That seems to be the wrong way round though. It makes more sense to show a badge when the user is not in the app…strange. Is correcting this as simple as me generating a push notification instead? I don’t store any data on a server so far - just within the app. All I’m trying to do is notify a user that there is an action/deadline coming up in 7 days time.
